# Как в FFMPEG записать видео с экрана с высокой частотой битрейта?

Tags: ffmpeg

Использую Windows os
Я пытаюсь записать видео с высокой частотой битрейта с экрана, через FFmpeg.
Я так-же записал видео через "OBS Studio" с частотой 60000 kbits/s
Хочу добиться похожего результата в FFMPEG.

```
set m="Stereo mixer (VIA HD Audio)"
ffmpeg -y -f gdigrab -rtbufsize 999999k -thread_queue_size 999999 -indexmem 999999 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio=%m% -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -b:v 50000K video.mp4
```

Comment: А чем эта команда не похожая? Чем результат отличается от ожидаемого?

Comment: @andreymal Средняя частота с которой я записываю видео этой командой это около 2000 kbits/s.. Битрейт снижается иногда до 1000 kbits/s.

Comment: Может, больше и не требуется? Если на экране ничего не происходит, то кодек и не сможет ниоткуда выдумать информацию, чтобы появился высокий битрейт. Или у вас картинка активно меняется и качество плохое?

Comment: @andreymal Нет всё статично.. Я записал видео (пустой экран рабочего стола) на программу OBS Studio и там оказался очень высокий битрейт. Я подумал, что чем выше битрейт тем лучше.. Может быть можно записать не в mp4 изначально а в какой-нибудь сырой формат, в который будет записываться с высокой частотой. А уже после когда видео будет записано в него, перекодировать следующей операцией в mp4?

Comment: Чем выше битрейт, тем хуже, потому что видео начинает весить больше и соответственно больше затраты на передачу данных. // Видеофайлы хранят в себе отличия кадров друг от друга; если картинка статичная и отличия между кадры минимальны, то и большому размеру взяться тоже неоткуда. Запишите например какую-нибудь динамичную игру — и будет вам высокий битрейт

Comment: А зачем записывать в сырой формат? Чего вы пытаетесь добиться?

Comment: @andreymal Ага спасибо. Я этого не знал.. Значит оставлю всё как было. 
Ну я как думал: если высокий битрейт при записи значит это хорошо. 
Вот и стремился к более высокому битрейту, но я не знал, от чего он растёт.. 
Думал может это зависит от каких-то параметров.. А оно вон как от отличия кадров друг от друга..

Comment: Можно тогда и вовсе удалить `-b:v 50000K` ненужный параметр..

Comment: Удалять не стоит, там по умолчанию может стоять какое-нибудь неприемлемое значение. А лучше вообще перейти от битрейта к опции регулировки качества (crf, чем меньше тем лучше), а битрейт сам подгонится под выбранное качество

Comment: @andreymal Ну у меня вообще вот так вот выглядит вся запись, я сюда кусок постил отдельный.. Хотя и это тоже отдельный кусок от всего бат файла.
`set m="Stereo mixer (VIA HD Audio)"`
`set a=-f gdigrab -framerate 25 -rtbufsize 999999k -thread_queue_size 9999999 -indexmem 9999999 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio=%m% -b:a 192k -audio_buffer_size 1000 -acodec libmp3lame -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 25 -crf 20 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency
set b="Result\video.mp4"
set c=ffmpeg`
`%c% -y %a% %b%` 
Не знаю я как перенос строк тут делать.. каша вышла